# Defining a probability space satisfying certain properties

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm relatively new to probability theory and I've been struggling on this exercise for quite a while.

Suppose we roll a dice $N$ times independently where $N$ is a random number. Let $A_n$ be the event, that '$N = n$' and let $S_M$ be the event, that the sum of the numbers on the dice equals $M$. We make two assumptions:

(a) The dice is fair,

(b) For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$.

How can we define a (discrete) probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega), \mathbb{P})$, such that conditions (a) and (b) are satisfied?

My initial idea was to define $\Omega$ as the set of all finite sequences $(\omega_1, \dots , \omega_k, 0, \dots )$ where each $\omega_i \in \{1, \dots , 6\}$ but then I don't know how condition (b) would be satisfied.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The probability of a getting a fixed sequence of length $n$ is $\frac 1{2^n}\times \frac 1{6^n}=\frac 1{12^n}$.

Comment: Right, because a set consisting of $n$ elements has exactly $2^n$ subsets and the probability $\frac{1}{6^n}$ comes from the fact that the dice is fair by condition (a). Hence for a finite sequence $(\omega_1, \dots , \omega_n)$ we define $\mathbb{P}((\omega_1, \dots \omega_n)) := \frac{1}{12^n}$. For an arbitrary subset $A \subset \Omega$ we can then define $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{\omega \in A} \mathbb{P}(\omega)$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Ok so, I've shown that $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$ and that condition (b) is satisfied. I'm struggling to show that (a) is satisfied though. If I'm not mistaken, condition (a) means that $\mathbb{P}(S_M \cap A_1) = \frac{1}{6}$ for $M \in \{1, \dots ,6\}$. But isn't that the same as $\mathbb{P}(S_M | A_1)$, which would mean that $\mathbb{P}(A_1) = 1$, which is clearly wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Fix $n$.  There are $6^n$ equally likely sequences, each of which has probability $\frac 1{6^n}$.  There are $6^{n-1}$ sequences that start with a $1$.  Hence the probability that you start with $1$, given that you have length $n$ is $\frac {6^{n-1}}{6^n}=\frac 16$.  Now just sum over all the possible lengths.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. I have to show that (a) is true, given the definition of $\mathbb{P}$. But $S_M \cap A_1 = \{(M)\}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{M\}) = \frac{1}{12}$. Hence this means that $\mathbb{P}(S_M | A_1) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(S_M \cap A_1)}{\mathbb{P}(A_1)} =  \frac{1}{6}$. However what I'm confused about: Aren't $\mathbb{P}(S_M \cap A_1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_M | A_1)$ supposed to be the same? Since $S_M \cap A_1$ means that we roll the dice one time and we get $M$ whereas $\mathbb{P}(S_M \cap A_1)$ is the probability that we roll $M$ under the assumption that we roll the dice once?

Comment: I don't understand.  What does $S_M$ have to do with it?  I thought the goal was to show that the die is fair, meaning that the probability that a given roll comes up $k$ is $\frac 16$ for $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: As described above, $S_M$ is the event "Sum of dice rolls equals $M$". Hence showing that the dice is fair means that we have to show $\mathbb{P}(S_M | A_1) = \frac{1}{6}$ given $M \in \{1, \dots , 6\}$. I don't understand your explanation, since you already assume that each of the $6^n$ sequences has probability $\frac{1}{6^n}$, which is what we are trying to show.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You just have to show that rolls are uniform and independent. The rest follows.